# Atmosphere: Multiple Clients for Managed Service

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, jetty, atmosphere

We have an embedded Jetty 9 application that we are trying to add Amosphere support to. The goal is to provide real-time data to AngularJS-based web application. We are using Atmosphere 2.1.3 (though we did try 2.2.0-SNAPSHOT as well).

The issue right now is that while the application works perfectly with one client, it fails with multiple clients: the first client stops and the new one takes over.

Here is the code that initializes Atmosphere in the server (class that instantiates and starts Jetty):

```
    ServletHolder atmosphereServletHolder = new ServletHolder(AtmosphereServlet.class);
    atmosphereServletHolder.setAsyncSupported(true);
    serviceContext.addServlet(atmosphereServletHolder, "/atmosphere/*");
```

Here is the Managed Service code (based on the chat example):

Annotations:

```
@ManagedService(path = "/atmosphere/values")
@Singleton
```

Code:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class);

@Ready(value = Ready.DELIVER_TO.ALL)
public final void onReady(final AtmosphereResource atmosphereResource){
    LOGGER.info("Browser {} connected.", atmosphereResource.uuid());
}

@Disconnect
public final void onDisconnect(final AtmosphereResourceEvent atmosphereResourceEvent){
    final String uuid = atmosphereResourceEvent.getResource().uuid();
    if(atmosphereResourceEvent.isCancelled()) {
        LOGGER.info("Browser {} unexpectedly disconnected", uuid);
    } else if(atmosphereResourceEvent.isClosedByClient()) {
        LOGGER.info("Browser {} closed the connection", uuid);
    }
}

@Message(encoders = {MessageEncoderDecoder.class})
public ListResponse list(Object test) {
    ...

    return new ListResponse(...);
}
```

Here is most of the client side (again, mostly based on the angular example). The data pushed into socket is meaningless since there are no arguments to the service:

```
    $scope.model = {
        transport: 'websocket',
        accounts: {}
    };

    var request = {
        url: '/atmosphere/values',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        logLevel: 'debug',
        transport: 'websocket',
        trackMessageLength: true,
        reconnectInterval: 5000,
        enableXDR: true,
        timeout: 600000
    };

    request.onOpen = function (response) {
        $scope.model.transport = response.transport;
        $scope.model.uuid = response.request.uuid;
        $scope.model.connected = true;
        $scope.model.content = 'Atmosphere connected using ' + response.transport;
        socket.push(angular.toJson({ test: 'test' }));
    };

    var socket = null;
    request.onClientTimeout = function (response) {
        $scope.model.content = 'Client closed the connection after a timeout. Reconnecting in ' + request.reconnectInterval;
        $scope.model.connected = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            socket = atmosphereService.subscribe(request);
        }, request.reconnectInterval);
    };

    request.onReopen = function (response) {
        $scope.model.connected = true;
        $scope.model.content = 'Atmosphere re-connected using ' + response.transport;
        socket.push(angular.toJson({ test: 'test' }));
    };

    ...

    request.onMessage = function (response) {
        var responseText = response.responseBody;
        try {
            $scope.model.values = angular.fromJson(responseText);
            socket.push(angular.toJson({ test: 'test' }));
        } catch (e) {
            $log.error("Error parsing JSON: ", responseText);
            throw e;
        }
    };

    ...

    socket = atmosphereService.subscribe(request);
```

So, what is missing to make this respond to all the clients and not just one?

Thanks!

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? Broadcast some message to all connected clients? And if a new client connects, it gets broadcasts, but the first client does not?

Comment: The logic is trying to provide data to multiple clients. When the connection is killed, the first client loses its connection. One of the clients is IE9 and all the issues are primarily with it. I can run Chrome and Firefox simultaneously but do have problems with IE9 once one of them connects.